# Load server data into jqgrid and hide record id

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I wonder how to ensure that the id column is hidden in the grid after I have loaded it with data fom the server but the id value should be available when selecting any visible cell in a row.

The data from the server looks like;

```
{ "rows": [  
[ "0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36","Name1","Telephone1","Mobile1","Workplace1" ] ,
[ "0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36","Name2","Telephone2","Mobile2","workplace2" ] 
]}
```

The grid code looks like;

```
// Load the grid
$( "#contentTable" ).jqGrid( {
url: jsonURL,
datatype: 'json',
autowidth: true, 
height: 520,
colNames: options.selectedColumnNames,
colModel: options.selectedColumnModel,
loadonce: true,
rownumbers: true,
rownumWidth: 40,
gridview: true,
pager: '#pager',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "asc",
jsonReader : {
cell: "",
id: "0"
},
caption: options.viewTitle
});
```

The column models looks like;

```
columnNames = ['ID', 'Namn','Telefon', 'Mobil', 'Arbetsplats'];
columnModel = [
        {name:'id',index:'name', width: 200},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width: 200},
    {name:'telephone',index:'telephone', width:100},
    {name:'mobile',index:'mobile', width:100},
    {name:'workplace',index:'workplace', width:200}     
];
```

My question is, can anybody help me clear out how I should do to hide the id column from displaying in the grid but I want still to be able to get the id value when selecting a cel in a row?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you mean under "id value should be available when selecting any visible cell in a row". I suppose that you mean that the first parameter of `onSelectRow` calback (the `id` or `rowid`) should have the value from the input data (`0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36`) for example.

First of all it's important to have **unique** id value. The data which you posted contains two rows with the same `id="0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36"`. I suppose that it's just cut&paste error and your real data contains really unique id values.

Next it's important to understand that one don't need to have hidden `id` column at all in the most scenarios. jqGrid *always* assign `id` attribute on every row of the grid (on `<tr>` elements). Callbacks like `onSelectRow` get the value from `id` attribute and not from some grid column. So the row of data can be reduced to

```html
<tr id="0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36">
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>Telephone1</td>
    <td>Mobile1</td>
    <td>Workplace1</td>
</tr>
```

instead of

```html
<tr id="0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36">
    <td style="display:none">0007A53CEC393D2CC1257BE3002AAC36</td>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>Telephone1</td>
    <td>Mobile1</td>
    <td>Workplace1</td>
</tr>
```

which corresponds to hidden `id` column.

The next remark. I don't recommend you to specify `index` column in the grid. Especially the usage of *different* `name` and `index` properties, like `name:'id',index:'name'` in your grid, can be origin of errors. The value of `index` which points on the name of `name` of another column will work, but I am not sure that it's just cut&paste error. If you use `loadonce: true` you can have problems with  `index` values other as `name` values of `colModel`.

If you still really need to have hidden `id` column you can use the following `colModel`

```js
colModel: [
    {name: 'id', key: true, hidden: true, width: 200},
    {name: 'name', width: 200},
    {name: 'telephone', width: 100},
    {name: 'mobile', width: 100},
    {name: 'workplace', width: 200}
],
jsonReader: {
    cell: "",
    id: "0"
}
```

like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Henrik.htm). Alternatively you can use

```js
colModel: [
    {name: 'name', width: 200, jsonmap: "1"},
    {name: 'telephone', width: 100, jsonmap: "2"},
    {name: 'mobile', width: 100, jsonmap: "3"},
    {name: 'workplace', width: 200, jsonmap: "4"}
],
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: function () {
        return function (item) {
            return item[0];
        };
    }
}
```

and have no hidden `id`, just `id` attribute. See [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Henrik1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$("#contentTable").jqGrid('hideCol','ID');
```